# Added a navbar to each of my React components, how do I mock the navbar in test as all tests failing as a method call in Navbar component is null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I am working on a project and was implementing tests for each component that I implemented. These tests were all passing but now fail because I have since added a AppNavbar component that makes a call to the AuthService to get the currently logged in user's id to create a dynamic Route link to profile for that user.

I tried mocking the AppNavbar using mockComponent(AppNavbar); but it gives me error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')
```

In my tests, this value is obviously null because no user is logged in. How can I mock away the navbar so it doesn't interfere with the tests? Or mock the value of the AuthService?

//LoginForm.test.js:

```
const server = setupServer(
rest.post(config.URL + "/auth/login", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json("Success."))
}),
)
beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())

const renderWithRouter = (element) => (
    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/sign-in']}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/sign-in' element={element} />
            </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>
    )
);

describe("loginForm", () => {
    it("should render the fields", () => {
        mockComponent(AppNavbar);
        renderWithRouter(<LoginForm />);
        expect(
            screen.getByRole("heading", { name: "Login" })
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Email Address:" })).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(
            screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Password:" })
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit" })).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
    it("should validate form fields", async () => {
        mockComponent(AppNavbar);
        renderWithRouter(<LoginForm />);
        fireEvent.input(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Email Address:" }), {
            target: {
                value:
                    "jojeaojoeaj@outlook.com"
            }
        });
        fireEvent.input(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Password:" }), {
            target: {
                value:
                    "password-1"
            }
        });

        fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit"}));
        console.log(await screen.findAllByRole("alert"));
        expect(await screen.findAllByRole("alert")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

//LoginForm.js:

```
   const defaultValues = {
    //The email to attempt to login with.
    email: "",
    //The password to attempt to login with.
    password: "",
};

export default function LoginForm() {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(defaultValues);
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState('');
    const [alertSeverity, setAlertSeverity] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        if (validateInput(values.email, values.password).includes("Failure: Email")) {
            setLoading(false);
            setAlertMessage("Login failed, please enter a valid email, emails must be between 4 and 50 characters.");
            setAlertSeverity("error");
            setAlert(true);
            return;
        }
        if (validateInput(values.email, values.password).includes("Failure: Password")) {
            setLoading(false);
            setAlertMessage("Login failed, please enter a valid password, passwords must be between 6 and 12 characters.");
            setAlertSeverity("error");
            setAlert(true);
            return;
        }
        const payload = {
            "email": values.email,
            "password": values.password,
        };

        setLoading(false);
        AuthService.loginUser(payload).then(response => response.json())
            .then(async data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.userId && data.accessToken) {
                        setAlertMessage("Login successful");
                        setAlertSeverity("success");
                        setAlert(true);

                        const authenticatedUser = {
                            "userId": data.userId,
                            "accessToken": data.accessToken,
                        }
                        localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', JSON.stringify(authenticatedUser));

                        await delay(1000);
                        navigate('/');
                    }
                }
            );
        setAlertMessage("Login failed, probably because no user exists with these credentials.");
        setAlertSeverity("error");
        setAlert(true);
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div id="loading">
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const validateInput = (email, password) => {
        if (email.length > 50) {
            return "Failure: Email entered is too long."
        }
        if (email.length < 4) {
            return "Failure: Email is invalid."
        }
        if (password.length > 12) {
            return "Failure: Password is too long."
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
            return "Failure: Password is too short."
        } else {
            return "Success."
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
            <AppNavbar />
            <div id="loginFormContainer">
                {alert ? <Alert severity={alertSeverity} role="alert">{alertMessage}</Alert> : <></> }
                <div id="loginFormDiv">
                    <h5 id="loginFormHeading">Login</h5>
                    <br />
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label className="formLabel">
                            <br />
                            Email Address:
                            <br />
                            <input
                                className="formInput"
                                value={values.email}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                name="email"
                                type="email"
                            />
                        </label>
                        <label className="formLabel">
                            <br />
                            Password:
                            <br />
                            <input
                                className="formInput"
                                value={values.password}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                name="password"
                            />
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <button id="form-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

//AppNavbar.js

```
export const AppNavbar = () => {

const userId = AuthService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser().userId;

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

return (
    <>
        <Navbar className="NavBar" color="dark" dark expand="sm">
            <NavbarBrand id="NavBarBrand" href="/">Po</NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />
            <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
                <Nav navbar className="ml-auto" id="Nav">
                    <NavItem className="NavLink">
                        <NavLink href={`/profile/${userId}`} className="NavLink">Profile</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                        <DropdownToggle nav caret >
                            Play
                        </DropdownToggle>
                        <DropdownMenu end>
                            <DropdownItem tag="a" href={'/players'}>
                                Players
                            </DropdownItem>
                            <DropdownItem tag="a" href={'/top-players'}>
                                Top Players
                            </DropdownItem>
                        </DropdownMenu>
                    </UncontrolledDropdown>
                    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                        <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                            Games
                        </DropdownToggle>
                        <DropdownMenu end>
                            <DropdownItem tag="a" href={'/record-game'}>
                                Record Game
                            </DropdownItem>
                            <DropdownItem tag="a" href={'/game-history'}>
                                Game History
                            </DropdownItem>
                        </DropdownMenu>
                    </UncontrolledDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </>
)
```

}

export default AppNavbar;

//AuthService.js:

```
getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"));
};
```

The tests are implemented using Jest/React-testing-library.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could mock the `AuthService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser` function.

Comment: Could you add the import statements too please?

Comment: @DrewReese How would I do that? Thanks

Comment: The top of your LoginForm.js file has a number of import statements that define the dependencies of the LoginForm. Specifically, we need to see the dependency for the AppNavbar. Then you should be able to mock it with a jest.mock('./AppNavBar') or whatever the path to the AppNavBar is.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

If the `AppNavBar` is on every page, you should create a container which renders the `AppNavBar` alongside any arbitrary page content. This will be much simpler to test, as you will be able to test each page in isolation from the `AppNavBar`.

```js
const Page = ({ children }) => {
    return <>
        <AppNavBar />
        {children}
    </>
}
```

This approach may also save some future headaches, as it's more consistent with [DRY principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

**Option 2**

If Option 1 doesn't suit your use case, you should just mock the whole component.

```js
// replace '../AppNavBar' with actual location of component
jest.mock('../AppNavBar', () => <>MOCK APP NAV</>);
```